# SFTP Oubound Gateway Error - File List Command

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

I have a sftp server with this directory structure :

```
main
--directoryA
  --subDirectory1
--directoryB
  --subDirectory1
```

But when I tried to get the directory list using sftp outbound gateway, I am getting this error :

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: main/directoryA/directoryA/subDirectory1
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2225) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2242) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1592) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1553) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:111) ~[spring-integration-sftp-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
... 47 common frames omitted
```

I'm not sure why the directoryA is appending twice. Here is my outbound gateway :

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="gateway"
  expression="payload"
  request-channel="request"
  remote-directory="main"
  command-options="-dirs -R"
  command="ls"
  session-factory="sessionFactory"
  reply-channel="reply">
</int-sftp:outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: Have you experimented eg. without recursive listing? Or giving directory with absolute path like "/main"

Comment: Yes, without the recursive it only returns the files on the main directory. I need also to check all sub directories path. I also tried giving that absolute path "/main". Still getting this error.

Comment: What the payload of the message do you send to this gateway?

Comment: <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="invoiceRequestChannel" expression="'/main'">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="30000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
  </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

Answer (score 1):

Look on the server logs to see if there are any clues there.

Maybe you don't have permissions to access that subdir?

```java
if(type!=SSH_FXP_ATTRS){
    if(type==SSH_FXP_STATUS){
      int i=buf.getInt();
      throwStatusError(buf, i);
    }
```

According to the stack trace, the server returned 101 (the client is expecting 105).

The value (i) does not appear in the `SftpException.getMessage()` shown in the stack trace.

You can see it by traversing the `cause()` chain and using `toString()`.

```java
public class SftpException extends Exception{
  //private static final long serialVersionUID=-5616888495583253811L;
  public int id;
  private Throwable cause=null;
  public SftpException (int id, String message) {
    super(message);
    this.id=id;
  }
  public SftpException (int id, String message, Throwable e) {
    super(message);
    this.id=id;
    this.cause=e;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return id+": "+getMessage();
  }
  public Throwable getCause(){
    return this.cause;
  }
}
```

It might provide more clues.

Comment: Hi Gary. Actually that subdir (main/directoryA/directoryA/subDirectory1) does not exist. That's why it gives me that error response. My questions is why it is double appends the /directoryA on the path. I'm am still figuring it out.

Comment: It's a bug - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3482

Comment: Thanks Gary! Do you have tentative date when will be the release for v.5.5?

Comment: 5.5 won't be out until late summer/early fall this year; but the fix has been applied on the 5.3 and 5.4 branches so you can test with the latest snapshots (`https://repo.spring.io/snapshot`) https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn. The releases are listed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/milestones The next 5.3 and 5.4 releases are not yet scheduled but will likely be mid-March. You should comment on the issue if you need a production-ready release before then so the team can consider when to schedule them.